# Going from PD3 (pollution degree 3) to PD2 using IP54 (ingress protection 54)?

Tags: protection, industrial, environmental-sealing, harsh-environment

I wonder what is needed to reduce a PD3 (pollution degree 3) environment to PD2?

It seems that IP54 housing could do it, but I have not found this clearly written in text (there is some vague mentioning of it in IEC 60664-1 Annex B, attached). However, I found this link where it is written "IP 54 rated enclosure alone does not provide a pollution degree 2 environment". How come I wonder?

https://www.iecex.com/dmsdocument/67

[image]

Comment: I don't have a full answer. Last time I did it we ended up with hermetically sealed and thus PD1. How's your cooling situation? Do you need airflow?

Comment: @winny Thanks for feedback! Currently, yes, we need aircooling.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue. The standard that specifies this is IEC 61010-1.

You have to follow the indications in table E.2 - Reduction of pollution degree. If your macro-environment is p.d. 3 then you could reduce the micro-environment to 2 by using an enclosure at least IPx7 (see the disclosure on maintenance conditions).

Comment: This answers the question spot on. Thanks for your help!